# AutoComplete Material-ui React getOptionSelected prop not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autocomplete, material-ui

I am fairly new to react, and would really appreciate some pointers here:

I have an autocomplete dropdown with certain set of options. I want one of them to be selected by default, based on a condition I have.

from what i understand this can be completed by [getOptionSelected prop](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props/) in Autocomplete.

I created a sample to test this, however this is not working as expected. Can you please help?

[CodeSandbox Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-r03m9?file=/demo.tsx)

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option: { title: string; year: number }) => option.title}
      getOptionSelected={(option) => option.year === 1994}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 }
];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**V5**

If you're updating to v5, `getOptionSelected` is renamed to `isOptionEqualToValue`. See the migration guide [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#heading-autocomplete).

**V4**

Use `getOptionSelected` only if you need to validate selected options, which may not be what you want here.

If you want to change the selected option based on a condition, you can modify the `value` props of the [`Autocomplete`](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api) component. In the demo below, you can change the selected option by specifying the option index in the `TextField`.

```
export default function Demo() {
  // Use null instead of undefined to fix mixing uncontrolled and controlled error
  // https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18173#issuecomment-552420187
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const onChangeOptionIndex = (e) => {
    const optionIndex = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    const selectedValue =
      top100Films.find((o, i) => i === optionIndex) || top100Films[0];

    setValue(selectedValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box display="flex">
      <TextField label="Option Index" onChange={onChangeOptionIndex} />
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        onChange={(_, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        value={value}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI Autocomplete Default Value]

Comment: The options I get are from an API based on text change in the input box. 
`<TextField {...params} onChange={this.onTextChange}/>
defaultValue={this.state.selectedOption || {}}`

the state.selectedOption during first render is null. And I get 
_A component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Autocomplete after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled Autocomplete._

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix the 'uncontrolled Autocomplete' error @Akash